# How do I install `Platypus` (and NaturallySpeaking 12 Premium) on Ubuntu 13.10 x64?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, wine, winetricks

For the record, I have all of the following packages installed on my machine:

- `wine`
- `wine-gecko1.4`
- `wine-gecko1.4:i386`
- `wine1.4`
- `wine1.4-amd64`
- `wine1.4-dev`
- `wine1.4-i386-i386`
- `winetricks`

I created a 32-bit Wine prefix using

```
$WINEPREFIX='/home/philvollman/.dictation' WINEARCH='win32' wine 'wineboot'
```

I have a legally acquired copy of Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12 Premium.

When I tried to install NaturallySpeaking, I got this error, and this screen:

[image: Error Message]

[image: Progress stopped]

However, there was no rollback and I was able to start and register my copy of NaturallySpeaking, which promptly stopped working thereafter:

After I installed NaturallySpeaking, I ran `ls -al` and found that my `.dictation` folders had the following top-level contents:

```
total 1816
drwxrwxr-x  4 philvollman philvollman    4096 Apr 10 00:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 63 philvollman philvollman    4096 Apr 10 00:27 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 philvollman philvollman    4096 Apr 10 00:27 dosdevices
drwxrwxr-x  5 philvollman philvollman    4096 Apr 10 00:28 drive_c
-rw-rw-r--  1 philvollman philvollman 1754254 Apr 10 00:39 system.reg
-rw-rw-r--  1 philvollman philvollman      11 Apr 10 00:27 .update-timestamp
-rw-rw-r--  1 philvollman philvollman    2376 Apr 10 00:34 userdef.reg
-rw-rw-r--  1 philvollman philvollman   75517 Apr 10 00:39 user.reg
```

The [Platypus](http://thenerdshow.com/platypus.html) installation directions told me to install Platypus as such:

```
export WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.dictation
./configure
make
make install
```

When I do this from inside the Platypus folder, I get:

```
Looking for winegcc...  (OK)
Checking WINEPREFIX...  (OK)
Checking LIBDIR...      /usr/lib
Checking winelib...     /usr/lib/wine/libwinecrt0.a not found!

 ERROR: Install wine-devel 32 bit
 or try one of these ./configure options:

    Configure options:
    --prefix=/usr           -p   Look for libraries starting in /usr
    --libdir=/lib           -l   Look for libraries in $PREFIX/lib
    --winelib=/opt/wine     -w   Location of libwinecrt0.a
    --with-64bit            -64  Compile as 64 bit
    --xincdir=/opt/include  -x   Optional includes in /opt/include
    --help                  -h   This help message
```

## Update

When I specify what I believe is the correct Wine library, this happens:

```
philvollman@phil-hp-envy:~/Downloads/platypus$ ./configure --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
Looking for winegcc...  (OK)
Checking WINEPREFIX...  (OK)
Checking LIBDIR...      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
Checking winelib...     (OK)
Checking xorg-proto...  (OK)
Checking libX11...      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu//libX11.so not found!

 ERROR: Install libX11-devel 32 bit
 or try one of these ./configure options:

    Configure options:
    --prefix=/usr           -p   Look for libraries starting in /usr
    --libdir=/lib           -l   Look for libraries in $PREFIX/lib
    --winelib=/opt/wine     -w   Location of libwinecrt0.a
    --with-64bit            -64  Compile as 64 bit
    --xincdir=/opt/include  -x   Optional includes in /opt/include
    --help                  -h   This help message
```

## Update #2

```
philvollman@phil-hp-envy:~$ sudo apt-get install wine-dev && sudo apt-get install libx11-dev && sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev && sudo apt-get install x11proto && sudo apt-get install x11proto-core-dev
[sudo] password for philvollman: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'wine1.4-dev' instead of 'wine-dev'
wine1.4-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libx11-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxtst-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package x11proto
philvollman@phil-hp-envy:~$
```

So, what do I do?

I see that the Platypus team writes that I need to install `wine-devel`, `xorg-x11-proto-devel`, `libX11-devel`, and `libXtst-devel`, but none of these packages appear to be available via Synaptic.

Comment: Isn't it fun when different distros call packages by different names? How about `wine-dev`, `libx11-dev`, `libxtst-dev`. You can also try `xserver-xorg-dev`, or some of the `x11proto` packages like `x11proto-core-dev`.

Comment: Hey, @Nattgew. Sorry for my (what I consider) late response; I'm going to install these packages now and see what happens... #fingerscrossed

Comment: Update #2: Read it and, IDK....

Comment: See if you can install `libx11-dev:i386`

Comment: Here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2282950/installation_of_libx11.htm

Comment: Oh, and now I get `Looking for winegcc...  (OK)`
`Checking WINEPREFIX...  (OK)`
`Checking LIBDIR...      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`
`Checking winelib...     (OK)`
`Checking xorg-proto...  (OK)`
`Checking libX11...      (OK)`
`Checking libXtst...     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu//libXtst.so not found!`

Comment: If `libxtst6:i386` doesn't clear that, then `libxtst-dev:i386`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think my issue is that each required file or directory is in a different top-level directory? And I'm not sure which flags to use to point towards them.

Comment: Well initially it stopped at "wine-devel", then "libX11-devel", then "libXtst", so it's making progress as the libraries get installed.